# Phone number verification service

Tags: phone

I'm looking for phone number verification service that has Java API or can be easily integrated into existing website.

I need to embed it into my website in order to verify users phone numbers.

I need to support phone numbers worldwide. Please suggest such service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please take a look at **twilio**.

It supports multiple ways to implement Verifikation like sending sms or call a number.